# Sync with remote encrypted storage

Tags: linux, ssh, encryption, sync, unison

I'm trying to keep a folder tree in sync between several computers. Currently, I'm using `unison` in a star topology, with a central remote server. I want the data on the server to be encrypted, so on the server, the `unison` tree (including the `.unison` folder) is kept inside an `encfs` tree. To perform a sync, each client:

- mounts the server storage with `sshfs`
- mounts the `encfs` storage over `sshfs` locally
- performs `unison` between the local copy of documents and the mounted one.

The setup has many advantages:

- open-source tools
- scriptable command-line solution
- secure communication over `ssh`
- privacy from server because the `encfs` folder tree is never decrypted there
- ability to diff modifications during sync, because `unison` runs over plaintext

One thing which doesn't work so well is the speed of the sync. Because the `encfs` folder from the server is mounted on the client, every `stat()` call the client does has to be forwarded over `ssh` to the server. The documents tree already has thousands of files, and a `unison` sync must perform at minimum one `stat()` call for each file (to rule out modifications w.r.t. the state stored in the `.unison` folder). Is there a faster alternative that maintains the advantages listed above?

Note: If I were to remove the last condition, I could run `unison` over cyphertext, and only mount the `encfs` tree locally. Then `unison` would run locally on the client and on the server, so `stat()` calls would be fast. But it's nice to have the option to see at least what files are being sync-ed; with `unison` over `encfs` cyphertext, file names would be encrypted.

I understand that to solve this problem, one has to efficiently transfer file metadata from the server to the client during the sync. I'm wondering whether there is a way (i.e., a combination of existing tools) to, e.g., store the metadata in one place, so that it is all transferred by sending only one (or a few) block(s) of data, instead of sending thousands of blocks (which is what forwarding `stat()` calls is doing).

What if I were to replace `encfs` by, say, an `ext4` over `dm-crypt` partition stored inside a large file on the server, and mounted on the client via `losetup` over `sshfs`? Would the `ext4` filesystem keep file metadata together, so that it gets transferred by sending a few blocks only? Would `sshfs` know to send only a few blocks during an update, instead of rewriting the whole encrypted file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had success with `ext4` over `luks` over `sshfs`. I find that running `unison` on a mount of this type is much, much faster than over `encfs` over `sshfs`. So it must be that those thousands of `stat()` structs are somehow bundled together in the `ext4` fs, so that they require less network traffic during a sync.

One thing which is slightly annoying is that the `ext4` filesystem needs a user id for every file, and this user id is used for computing access permissions when the `ext4` fs is mounted locally on a client. In my case, I chose to change my local user id to a specific number on *all* the clients I'm sync-ing from. The alternative would be to store the files in the `ext4` fs with uid 0, then use `bindfs` to mount the `ext4` fs with non-root uid.